# Re-installing Python using Chocolatey doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, python, chocolatey

Recently, I installed Python 3.8 using **Chocolatey** via **Windows PowerShell** on **Windows 10**. That was successful and added a new folder C:\Python38.

However, I wanted to downgrade to a lower version of Python so I uninstalled Python by running:

```
choco uninstall python
```

And also deleted the Python38 folder.

Then, I tried installing Python 3.7 by running

```
choco install python
```

Which gives me the following

```
Chocolatey v0.10.15
Installing the following packages:
python
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
Progress: Downloading python 3.7.3... 100%

python3 v3.7.3 [Approved]
python3 package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
Installing 64-bit python3...
python3 has been installed.
Installed to: 'C:\Python37'
 The install of python3 was successful.
  Software installed as 'exe', install location is likely default.

python v3.7.3 [Approved]
python package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
 The install of python was successful.
  Software install location not explicitly set, could be in package or
  default install location if installer.

Chocolatey installed 2/2 packages.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
```

However, checking my system, there is no `C:\Python37`. And through searching my system, I can't find any evidence that the installation process managed to actually add new Python files to my system.

As a test, I also tried reinstalling Python 3.8 using Chocolatey and while the installation says it was successful and was `Installed to: 'C:\Python38'`, it never actually shows up on my hard drive.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, which I solved by deleting the folders:

```
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\python
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\python3
```

Only after deleting this folders, choco is installing python for real (the process takes much longer).

Comment: Choco said it installed Python3.9.1 (installation was quick), when I start python from powershell it leads me to the MS Store to install python. I have the same folders and will try to delete and then install it again. I get `Failures
 - python3 (exited 1603) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\python3\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.`